# How to see changes I've made in VSTS project?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have made a few check-ins over the past few months to another developers project in a VSTS repository (under TFVC not GIT).

I now want to see all the changes I've made.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "Code" tab in the web UI, click on the "History" tab, and then set the filter to your username.

[image]
[image]